# How to append a list with certain data from a .dat file?

Tags: python, list, append

I have an empty list
x = []
and have a .dat file with multiple different lines. I want to append the empty list with only the last 5 lines of the .dat file.

Answer (score 1):

If your `.dat` file contains text, you could read all the lines of it into a list with the `readlines` method. From there, you can use `x.extend` to extend x with the last five lines as follows:

```
x = []
with open('file.dat', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
x.extend(lines[-5:])
print(x)
```

Here, `lines[-5:]` means to start at the 5th item from the end and then go to the end.

Using the `extend` method is simpler, but you could replace it with a for loop to see how to do it with `append`:

```
x = []
with open('file.dat', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines[-5:]:
    x.append(line)
print(x)
```